# Contact form not parsing all fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, contact-form, nodemailer, body-parser

I have created a contact form for users to email through a web app. The fields on the form are Name, Company, Contact Number and Message. When I tested the app the email sends but it only sends the data from the message input and the remain blank.

app.js file

```
 let mailOptions = {
            from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <**********>', // sender address
            to: '*************', // list of receivers
            subject: 'TW Contact Request', // Subject line
            Name:  req.body.Name,
            Company: req.body.Company,
            Phone: req.body.Phone,
            message: req.body.Body, // plain text body
            html: req.body.body // html body
        };
```

index.ejs file

```
<form action="/send-email" method="post">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="Company">Company:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Company">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="Phone">Contact Number:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Phone">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="body">Message:</label>
                        <textarea cols="5" rows="5"class="form-control" name="body"></textarea>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

I cant see why it is not pulling all the data.

Comment: What does the `req.body` contain?

Comment: Please use console.log  for show request data

Comment: @Nuhman it should contain whatever the user inputs on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code for getting request data

```
 var express = require("express");
 var myParser = require("body-parser");
 var app = express();
 app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
```

Comment: Sorry I have included that at the top of app.js. I didn’t want to include the full file.